# Save google map polygon into MySQL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps Save Polygon and points in MySQL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161350/google-maps-save-polygon-and-points-in-mysql-using-php)

In my project i have to provide the client(food company) with a google map on which it will define its custom local areas by drawing polygon on google map. I have done up to this.

What i  want is to know how to save this polygon so that i can determine whether a customer(whose latlong is known) is within tat area or not.Im using google map api 3.

Comment: Yeah i have read that post. All it says is about some ways to do it and same repeated links redirecting to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en).
A more specific way with some coding will close this type of question for once and all. THANKS for your HELP.

Comment: I have understood one way of doing it is get the co-ordinates as user clicks the map and then on final auto completion pass tat array to Polygon constructor. But is it the right way to do it ? or is thr some easier method or something provided by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method provided by Google to save a polygon to MySql.  If you have the polygon displayed on the map, iterate through the vertices of the polygon and send them to your server for storage in MySql.

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5b.html), outputs the modified polygons as JSON or KML, modified from [this project](http://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/)

Comment: Is this the standard practice ?

Comment: It is how I would do it if I had a MySQL database and wanted to save a polygon.  How complex are the polygons you need to save?

Comment: Vary simple ones. Polygon within polygon is out of scope.

Comment: So what is the problem you are having doing that?

Comment: Actually i was wondering (and hoping) if there was some ready made method provided by google.

Comment: After user draws the polygon on map, how do i get the ref to that polygons so as to iterate its vertices ?

Comment: How does the user draw the polygon on the map? [Drawing-tools](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools), something else?

Comment: added an example to my answer

Comment: The example is no longer available.

Comment: Updated to working link.